# how to update user status offline in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating users status update script in PHP MYSQL. I have added strtotime update to status column within the 24 second. but my script not updating offline I want to add NOW() date time to update offline status column.

Here is my source code

```
<?php
$time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-24 seconds', time()));

if($stmt = $con->prepare( "UPDATE users SET status = 'offline' WHERE time='".$time."' NOW()")){

$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `WHERE time = NOW() + INTERVAL 24 SECOND`?  It is a little unclear what you mean by "I want to add NOW() date time to update offline status column"

Comment: You're using the `=` operator, which requires an exact match. You probably want `<=` (or `>=`, whichever.)

Comment: i checked but same result

Comment: You checked _what_?  It game the same result _as what_?

Comment: not updating status column

Comment: Anyone can help me plz i have lot of tried to update status offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to

```
// set offline flag on all inactive users
"UPDATE users SET status='offline' WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 SECOND;"

// then flag current user as active
"UPDATE users SET status='online', time=NOW() WHERE id=321;"
```

Then you can get list of online users

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='online';"

or

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 SECOND;"
```

also it is better to store users status in a specified table
also use of `memory` database engine for status table
also use of integer instead of string; **0**='offline' ,  **1**='online'
also use of `timestamp` as integer instead of `datetime`